# AIChE Journal: Format file for LaTeX

Tags: document-classes

I want to submit my article in AIChE Journal and don't know how to format my manuscript with AIChE Journal format. Please help me and provide me a LaTeX sample file for AIChE Journal. I am a bit new to LaTeX.

Comment: check they accept latex file ie .tex files... URL:http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/%28ISSN%291547-5905/homepage/ForAuthors.html // Submit article at http://mc.manuscriptcentral.com/aiche

Comment: Not everyone knows what 'Aiche journal' is.  You should at least provide a link to the journal's website, and, ideally to where they discuss submission guidelines.

Comment: According to their site, they accept LaTeX submissions, but they do not seem to provide a class file. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1547-5905/homepage/ForAuthors.html

Comment: The link that I provided talks about the only guidelines I can find. They mostly seem like guidelines on content and spacing. I can't see anything that really requires special formatting. You can download a .bst file for formatting your references from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc.

Comment: @JohnReed Could you turn you comments into an answer?

Comment: @JosephWright Done.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the AIChE Journal site](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/%28ISSN%291547-5905/homepage/ForAuthors.html) they accept LaTeX submissions, but they do not seem to provide a class file.

> Submit your manuscript as a Word, rtf, or **LaTeX/TeX** file (for text and tables)and tiff or eps (for figures)...

The guidelines listed on their site seem to only cover content and spacing. I can't see anything that requires special formatting. If you need to format your references you can download a .bst file for formatting from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc).