# ScholarOne and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, journal-publishing

I'm trying to submit a journal paper through `ScholarOne Manuscript` (an outdated automatic build system some scientific journals use). The issue is that I'm using `biblatex`. I tried with both backends, `biber` and `bibtex`, and I couldn't get it through. Has any of you managed to make a successful submission to `ScholarOne` with `biblatex`?

**Update:** They use some build tool which forcefully calls `bibtex`. After many unsuccessful attempts to make it work with `biblatex` (also with `backend=bibtex`), I decided to convert everything to `bibtex`. The main issue is their referencing style: a mix of author-numeric(superscript) which I was not able to replicate easily without `biblatex` and I had to hardcode some citations:

[image]

[image]

If you have a better idea regarding the citation style let me know although maybe I should open a new question for that.

Comment: I fear that is very likely doomed to failure (especially because you call the system "outdated" yourself), see [`biblatex` submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). You are better of trying to use BibTeX (preferably with the journal's `.bst`) or even manual solutions.

Comment: I did some googling and it seems that no-one even thought that you would be using `biblatex`. They have some guidances on using BibTeX though, [Submitting TeX to ScholarOne](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11881), [Using BibTeX when submitting an article](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/14743), [A Guide for MMA Journal](http://inga.vgtu.lt/~art/SubmitGuide_MMA.pdf). It is really only your journal editor/publisher that can help you here, check if they have a template and use that, check if they have a `.bst` file and use that, if you find nothing, ask them.

Comment: @moewe I made an update to the question. They (AIChE Journal, Wiley) don't have a latex template. The main issue is their bibliography style - see the screenshots. Do you have a better idea how to achieve that with natbib, bibtex?

Comment: There is a difference between being able to run BibTeX and being able to run `biblatex` with BibTeX as backend, in the latter case for one they would have to have a reasonably new TeX system as well as all the required packages. Best would be to ask someone who has submitted to the journal (or if you can't the editor) how citations in TeX are normally handled. Depending on what style you use `\citet` (in natbib) might be OK, though I think that your problem of having to name names only arises if you make the citation an object (or subject) in your sentence.

Comment: If you just say "Water is liquid at room temperature\cite{foo}" that would be fine and in that case you only need the citation number, so I guess you only need to do the cases where you need an object or subject in your sentences by hand.

Comment: Anyway, if you want a `natbib` solution (are you sure they are OK with `natbib`?) or using another package it would be best to start a new question for that.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I could change semantics and remove those author-number situations. I might just do that. `natbib` works fine - I get the pdf proofs built with their system.

Comment: Now here is something that might help: [AIChE Journal: Format file for LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58861/35864) and especially .... tada .... [`aichej.bst` - a bi­b­li­og­ra­phy style file for the AIChE Jour­nal](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/aichej.bst). There is a cryptic comment about using LaTeX versions <= 2.02 (??? do they mean LaTeX2e?) in [AIChE Journal: Author Guidelines](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/%28ISSN%291547-5905/homepage/ForAuthors.html)

Comment: You can keep your sentence structure, you would just have to write the author names (i.e. the noun) yourself.

Comment: What did you end up doing in the end? If you want you can add an answer yourself and accept that. We could also close this as a duplicate of [biblatex submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864) or [AIChE Journal: Format file for LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58861/35864)

Comment: @moewe I converted the paper to be compatible with bibtex. Regarding the citation style (author + number in superscript): I hardcoded the author name and used a numerical bibliography style. Everything went fine and the paper is submitted now. I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the paper to be compatible with `bibtex`. Regarding the citation style (author + number in superscript): I hardcoded the author name and used a numerical bibliography style (`aichej.bst`). Everything went fine and the paper is submitted now.

I guess it will take a while till they make their systems compatible with `biblatex`.

Comment: To be honest, although a nice automatic match between the text and the citation would handy (and is easy in biblatex), the way you are using the authors' names is as part of the body text anyway and possibly beyond the remit of your citation typesetter.  It's a bit of an edge case when you're citing a method, rather than a fact -- here it's helpful (to the reader) to give the authors' names, while there's no fundamental difference between "Smith discovered in 1987 that" and "It was discovered in 1987 that".